# Update multiple documents by array of objects field value in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is my Schema.

```
 Home = new Schema({
        name: { type: String, required: true},
        description: {type: String},
        administrator: {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},

    users: [{ 
        _id: {type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
        email: {type: String},
        name: { type: String},
        status: { type: Number}
    }],
    rooms: [Room]


});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Home', Home);
```

If I want to find a specific user across multiple documents, I could do

> Home.find({"users.email": "johnk@gmail.com"},{users:1})

This would return all homes with users.email = johnk@gmail.com

But the user's field is an array.

```
"users" : [
        {
            "status" : 0,
            "name" : "Yaknow",
            "email" : "yaknow@gmai.com",
            "_id" : ObjectId("5875a42ea469f40c684de385")
        },
        {
            "status" : 1,
            "name" : "johnk",
            "email" : "johnk@gmail.com",
            "_id" : ObjectId("586e31c6ce07af6f891f80fd")
        }
    ]
```

(this is just from one home, if there are many homes, there will be many arrays like this)
So the above query will return each user array of each home the user has email in. 
My question is, how do I update all instances of that JohnK into JohnKirtster? 
Using this would update every user in the array's name to JohnKirster

> Home.update(query, {users.name: "JohnKirster"})

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use mongodb [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) by setting `multi:true`

```
Home.update(
 {"users.name": "johnk"}, //query, you can also query for email
 {$set: {"users.$.name": "JohnKirster"}},
 {"multi": true} //for multiple documents
)
```

Comment: This does the trick. Haven't used the positional operator before. A small type though, {"multi": true}, but yes, this solves it.

Comment: How can I update the fields in a bulk? ex - users.email, users.address, users.first, etc. In this case I have a users object. I do not want to mention each field. I want something like {$set: {"users.$.": users}}

Comment: @VikasChauhan, you can achieve that using `{$set: {"users.$": user}}`. i.e `user` is entire user object

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja thanks, I tried this too but not working.
I found a way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using updateMany function along with arrayFilter option

```
Home.updateMany(
{'users.name': 'johnk'}, //matches the condition to fetch documents
{ $set: { 'users.$[elem].name': 'johndoe' }}, //updates matched documents
{ arrayFilters: [{ 'elem.name': 'johnk' }] //filter documents to update
})
```